# How to set font-size globally in Angular7 (to set custom value to rem)?

Tags: css, angular7

I want to set rem into multiples of 10px in my Angular7 project. I tried changing the font-size in the body & HTML tags in my component's CSS file. But it doesn't seem to work. I want to know how to set custom font-size (and rem) locally(ie.for a component) and globally(ie.for the entire project)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global CSS can be set on your main styles.scss (or css), as specified on your index.html.

Component scoped CSS can be set by specifying your path to your scss (or css) file within the component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sample-component',
  templateUrl: './sample-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample-component.component.scss']
})
```

And in sample-component.component.scss, the * selector selects all elements encapsulated within the component

```
* { 
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```